# SPFX Custom CSS and deploy in CDN

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, spfx, spfx-extensions

I am creating SPFx extension with custom CSS file not SCSS file.

My Question is how can I add path in `SPComponentLoader.loadCss()`?

And at the same time how can I upload the file in my "Public Office 365 CDN"?

Can somebody help me?

Comment: you can add your css file in SytleLibrairy/custom and register the file in master page?

Comment: If you see question then I  mention that I am using spfx, mordern sites so I will not have masterpages

Comment: you can use twice, we use this solution on our project

Comment: ok i solved the issue :) by using require

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to add the CSS in SPFx project.

**Solution 1**

1. Create a folder for CSS and store all of the CSS files.

   [image]
2. Import all of the CSS files for example bootstrap, custom CSS, and other in a single file so that you can add that single file in your solution.

[image]

3. Add that file in your component tsx file.

```
import '../../../css/appStyle.css';
```

**Solution 2**

Use SPComponentLoader to add the CSS. Goto the *Webpart ts file and follow the steps.

1. Import SPComponentLoader in top section.

   ```
   import { SPComponentLoader } from '@microsoft/sp-loader';
   ```

   Write the line in render() method

`SPComponentLoader.loadCss(' https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');`

Comment: add one more method require :)

Comment: One of the nice answer